# Submit form and print page with python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I have been reading a lot on how to submit a form with python and then read and scrap the obtained page. However I do not manage to do it in the specific form I am filling. My code returns the html of the form page. Here is my code :

```
import requests 

values = {}
values['archive'] = "1"
values['descripteur[]'] = ["mc82", "mc84"]
values['typeavis[]'] = ["10","6","7","8","9"]
values['dateparutionmin'] = "01/01/2015"
values['dateparutionmax'] = "31/12/2015"
req = requests.post('https://www.boamp.fr/avis/archives', data=values)
print req.text
```

Any suggestion appreciated.

req.text looks like :

[image]

Comment: If its a website using javascript, you'll need to use something that can handle javascript, like selenium. Can you post a link to the site?

Comment: can you please upload your `req,text` ???

Comment: @SPYBUG96 : the website is https://www.boamp.fr/recherche/avancee

Comment: @ddor254 req.text is extremely long and I do not manage to add it properly so I uploaded a picture.

Comment: What is the error? Does this differ from what you get if you fill in the form manually?

Comment: @New2Python Yes it corresponds to the html of the form page, not the result page.

Answer (score 0):

You may post data to a wrong page. I access the url and post one, then i found the post data is sent to `https://www.boamp.fr/avis/liste`. (sometime fiddler is useful to figure out the process)

So your code should be this

```
req = requests.post('https://www.boamp.fr/avis/liste', data=values)
```